# Object.forEach polyfill not working on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

i'm using forEach which of course IE doesn't like. I have added the polyfill which is provided from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), however this only gets binded to the Array prototype.

So IE is still complaining as Object type doesn't suuport forEach

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'

Should I not be using forEach on an `Object`? Which works fine on all other browsers!

An example of how i'm using `forEach`:

```
var elements = {
    'test1': 'hello',
    'test2': 'world'
};
elements.forEach(function(element, i) {

    console.log(element);

}
```

Comment: If you want to use forEach on an object, you can either iterate over it using `Object.keys(elements).forEach(k => { elements[k] })` or using lodash or a similar library

Comment: `forEach is` for arrays. Not for objects - https://i.imgur.com/JR6LNYq.jpg

Comment: Object does not have the forEach

Comment: You mean you stll have to support IE<9 ..? @gillyhl That would need a polyfill for the arrow function ...

Comment: @Teemu oh yeah, damn IE

Comment: "_Which works fine on all other browsers!_" Definitely that won't work in any browser. Are you mixing JS objects and the hosted [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) objects? The latter has `forEach` method in the modern browsers, but not in IEs.

Comment: @Teemu I was doing a forEach on a NodeList, this could of been my confusion as to why it was working on an Object! This all makes sense now!